# Budgeting Option Calculator

Tags: php, calculator

I am wondering how I might be able to go about putting together a budgeting calculator for potential clients in which the following is able to occur.

- client enters their operating budget
- client checks boxes for each applicable goal they wish to achieve
- Each service & how much they should spend on that service is displayed
- If 1 service is displayed - that service equals 100% of budget
- If 2 services are displayed - both services share the budget in a weighted manner (i.e. 60%/40%, 50%/50%, 70%/30%, etc. based on whatever is recommended for that industry)
- Continues for 3,4, or more services.

The reason for this question is that the % of a budget allocated to each service should change according to the 'big picture', but the final total should always equal 100%.

I imagine there are many possible combination outcomes. ...am I looking at a monster of a project? Can this be done in PHP?

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is for helping with specific code, it's not for trying to solicit for developers (in answer to your question, yes it can be done in PHP or any other Turing-complete programming language).

Comment: No solicitation of developers was given. Thank you for the latter half of your answer - it was useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its possible with the right amount of planning. If you follow an SDLC even if its just you, you shouldnt have any issues

Comment: This isn't really an answer

Comment: Not sure what else to say he just asks if it is possible and if it is a monster of a project

Comment: You're not suppose to say anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add more details to your question for a more specific answer, but the math is pretty simply.

If you apply weights to each service, then you calculate the sum of weights of all selected services, divide to create percentage and use that to calculate overall spend:

```
$budget = 10000;
//service name => weight
$selectedServices = [
    'one'=>6,
    'two'=>3,
    'three'=>9,
    'four'=>2
];

$totalWeights= array_sum($selectedServices);

foreach($selectedServices as $key => $item){
    $percent = $item / ($totalWeights /100);
    $cost = $budget * ($percent/100);
    echo sprintf("<p>Service %s will cost %s of your budget (£%s)</p>", $key, $percent, $cost);
}
```